# ¿Cómo obtener el valor menor de dato duplicado en Excel?

Tags: excel, formulas

Tengo dos columnas, la primera se llama `usuarioid` que contiene valores duplicado, y  la segunda se llama `contactoid` que contiene el `id` de cada registro. Deseo quedarme con el valor menor de cada `usuarioid` duplicado.

¿Cómo lo puedo hacer en *Excel*?

```
usuarioid   contactoid
2064        1594
2064        1262
2065        1595
2065        1261
2066        1596
2066        1260
```

Answer (score 1):

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]1. Ordena por la columna usuarioid y contactoid, ambas de menor a mayor.
2. Elimina duplicados, sólo por la columna usuarioid.

Espero que sea la respuesta que buscas.

Answer (score 0):

Tienes varias opciones. Una que funciona en todas las versiones de Excel es resumir los datos con una tabla dinámica:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Una vez creada, te llevas el campo `usuarioid` al área de filas y `contactoid` al área de valores. Configura `contactoid` para que muestre el valor mínimo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Así te queda justo lo que quieres, con unos pocos clicks:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

> **[Crear una tabla dinámica para analizar datos de una hoja de cálculo](https://support.office.com/es-es/article/crear-una-tabla-din%C3%A1mica-para-analizar-datos-de-una-hoja-de-c%C3%A1lculo-a9a84538-bfe9-40a9-a8e9-f99134456576)**

Otra opción, si tienes una versión de Excel reciente (2019 o superior) es usar la fórmula MIN.SI.CONJUNTO:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mi fórmula en E2 es `=MIN.SI.CONJUNTO($B$2:$B$7;$A$2:$A$7;D2)`

> **[(función MIN.SI.CONJUNTO](https://support.office.com/es-es/article/min-si-conjunto-funci%C3%B3n-min-si-conjunto-6ca1ddaa-079b-4e74-80cc-72eef32e6599)**

Espero que te sirva.